# Can 'ps' combine processes?

Tags: shell, ps

I created a command to show me what processes eat RAM

```
alias psmem='ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,args --sort -pmem --columns $(tput cols) | head -25'
```

However, the output typically looks like this:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM COMMAND
barafu      2113  5.8  2.4 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-oop-rasterization --field-trial-handle=
barafu      1489  4.6  1.8 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle= --enable-gpu-raster
barafu      2765  0.6  1.8 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-oop-rasterization --field-trial-handle=
barafu      1460  1.7  1.7 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --password-store=basic --ignore-gpu-blacklist --enable-gpu-rasterization --enable-zero-copy --enable-oop-
barafu      1326  2.0  1.5 cinnamon --replace
barafu      1594  0.1  1.3 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-oop-rasterization --field-trial-handle=
```

**Question:** Is there a way to tell `ps` to combine all those chromiums into one entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ps`’s output granurality is limited to individual processes or threads, it can’t merge processes. You’ll have to post-process its output.

Something like this should get you started:

```
ps -eo user=,pid=,pcpu=,pmem=,args= --sort -pmem --columns $(tput cols) |
awk '{ cpu[$1][$5] += $3; mem[$1][$5] += $4 } END { for (user in cpu) { for (cmd in cpu[user]) { print user, cpu[user][cmd], mem[user][cmd], cmd } } }' |
sort -k3,3nr | head -n 25
```

Comment: If you add `| column -t -s' '` at the end of the line, you get a readable output!